# Google Sheets C# API - "Execution of Request Failed" when Inserting row into Sheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google Sheets API, and ran into an error that I'm not sure how to fix. When I attempt to insert a row into my sheet, it tells me that the "Execution of Request Failed" with a URL and no further information. I've run into this issue before, and found out how to create a key and have authorized access to the sheet. I can edit pre-existing rows just fine, as well as read in the data; but inserting rows isn't allowed. Here's the stack trace:

```
at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
at Google.GData.Client.Service.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Google.GData.Client.IService.Insert(AtomFeed feed, AtomEntry entry)
at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](AtomFeed feed, TEntry entry)
```

Here is the code that I am using for my sheet:

```
public static void WriteDataToLine(SpreadsheetsService service, WorksheetEntry sheet, string keyId, int row, 
        params string[] data)
    {
        AtomLink listFeedLink = sheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);

        ListQuery query = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString() + "?key=" + keyId);
        ListFeed feed = service.Query(query);

        if (feed.Entries.Count > row)
        {
            // Write over a preexisting row
            ListEntry entry = (ListEntry)feed.Entries[row];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                entry.Elements[i].Value = data[i];
            }
            entry.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            // Add a new row
            ListEntry entry = new ListEntry();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                entry.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom { Value = data[i] });
            }
            service.Insert(feed, entry);
        }
    }
```

In addition to the extension of "?key=" (plus the keyId) at the end of the URL (which, by the way, I got the same error before adding this authentication), I am using a Key.p12 file with a `X509Certificate2` object. These are two things that I have seen help with authenticating access to a sheet, but they are still not working.

One last thing: I have managed to access the URL given by the error message through my web browser. It's simply a bunch of XML, yet I get an error when using the API.

EDIT: I uninstalled the previous packages I had and installed the Google Sheets API v4. I am still getting the same issue, and can still edit rows but not insert rows.

Comment: If you switch to the v4 API, I suspect you may have an easier time obtaining information / help. v3 docs are basically gone, as it is flagged "legacy". https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/ I will note that you either need an authorized service account with access to the file, or OAuth2 access token, in order to modify Google Sheets data (even if publically, anonymously writable).

Comment: @tehhowch I have upgraded to v4, and also already have an authorized service account. The account is able to write to an existing row, but inserting rows is not working.

Comment: You should clarify what is "not working". Is the error message when using the v4 API still the same?

Comment: @tehhowch Yes, I am receiving the same error message as before.

Comment: if you switched to v4 please edit your question and inlucde your code for v4.  remove the gdata stuff as you are no loger using that.   we need to see how you are logging in and make sure you shared the service account email address with the sheet in question so that it has access.